# import org.springframework.web cannot be resolved (gradle)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

The import org.springframework.web cannot be resolved occurs on following lines:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
[...]

@RestController
[...]
@RequestMapping("/")
[...]
```

This Occurs in my Spring Starter Project.
I am using Spring with Gradle 2.x

I often read that you need to change your dependencies in the build.gradle file, but i dont know what to add in there. My dependencies looks as follows:

```
dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: How about `spring-boot-starter-web` if you want to do web development..

Answer (score 11):

You need to add 
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

Check this https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#scratch

Comment: Thanks for this! In newest Gradle versions it's `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")`

Comment: I just like to add one in depth comment to your answer. If you want to make a spring boot web starter app you need to click on the war option as packaging style. That will automatically add the code you mentioned in the **spring boot initializer** [link] (https://start.spring.io/)

Answer (score -1):

I added

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

to my build.gradle file under the dependencies {}.

It worked for me.